# Is it true that you need atleast 350 colors to color-in the boundries of a flat map where all the boundries are clearly defined?

Tags: geometry, coloring, map-projections, cartography

Since a providence may build on a bridge, and since certain bridges may be placed as archways over land: it is an obvious fact that this Earth could be turned into a topological and territoried donut/torroid; therefore, l assume it is one, needing 7 colors to be properly colored-in as a globe. As a flat map however; the underside and underneath portions of the bridge [and their territories] would be invisible, unless we gave them something akin to transparency; so let's do that. We will add a color for every possible permutation of overlap between the seven types of colorful territory. A bridge has: a "top" (where people walk); an "underside" (that people look up at, and can hang from); and an "underneath" (which is a path that passes under, both: the top, and the underside). This means that there are atleast 3 positions that a color can be on, so we will give this model the variable: "K" = 3; and the variable "N" = 7. To get every permutation of every ordered color-overlap which can appear on the bridge, we simple do: 7^3, to get the answer: 343. Then we add: 7 to 343, because there is also the possibility of surrounding flat areas, which gives us the answer 350. Right? So does one need atleast 350 colors to adequately color-in the boundries of a map of any given real places on the surface our Earth? Am I being too generous? Does it need more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not true. You can color any map on a torus *of genus 1* (that is a donut, or a normal cup with one handle) with at most 7 colors. But the higher the genus, the more colors you need. Any bridge you add increases the genus, so there is no a-priori limit on the number of colors needed.

There is a formula giving a lower bound to the minimum number of colors for any map on an orientable surface (like Earth with $n$ bridges), which has been conjectured in 1890 and completely proven in 1968. This is a lower bound, which gives $4$ for a sphere. It doesn't say that the bound is strict, there might be surfaces where you can't attain the bound. Still the bound is increasing and unlimited, the higher the genus (number of bridges) the more colors you need.

This is the formula:
$$
\left\lfloor
\frac{7+\sqrt{1+48g}}{2}
\right\rfloor
$$

Comment: I was reading the answers but now they all say "[math processing error]" is it doing that on your end too?

Comment: You seem to know your stuff. My gut says to click your answer

Comment: I'm bummed that I'm seeing this: " [Math Processing Error] " instead of your explanation though, I was in the middle of reading; and then everything flickered [flickered and then changed to something glitchy/unreadable]

Comment: The stuff is back, I see it; it's neat, and your answer is logical. I think my flaw was in imagining a world with only one bridge. Or perhaps I meant to describe a kingdom with only one... either way: I think I'm getting it. I am curious if I am right, for a kingdom with only one archway landmass, with subdivided states though; I'm not sure if I wanna go through the trouble of askimg a whole other question though... Am I? Or no?

Comment: If you have only one bridge, 7 colors are always enough.

Comment: You misunderstand. Seven colors are only enough for a globe with one bridge. A flat projection of that bridge [seems to me to] require(s) more colors due to the possibility of Z-axis overlap.

Comment: It is unclear as what you consider a "flat map" or "flat projection". If you just project radially on a sphere, then you have just a map on a sphere, for which you need at most 4 colors, independently of the original map.

Comment: I mean, if you have a 3D navigable map: than yes: you only need seven. But if you have a birds-eye-view of that 3D map, but as a flat non-navigable projection (imagine it drawn on a flat piece of paper), yet you still wanted to show the territories under the bridge: then you need way more than seven colors [to account for overlapping territory colors, and to distinguish between the layering [orders/sequence] of the overlap]

Comment: You have a bridge; that bridge is on a flat plane; the bridge and the flat plane have so many countries of such variety that they require seven colors to fill in with no boundries of matching color. Then: you go up into the sky, you look down on the bridge, and you use your X-ray vision so that you can see all the territories under the bridge; then you draw it as a flat map on the surface of a flat rectangular piece of paper. My math says that someone needs 350 colors to exceed at that endeavor in that exact scenario.

Comment: As soon as you put your map in a rectangular sheet, you need only 4 colors to color it. In some sense, the "projection" helps the colorer, by adding new boundaries on existing regions. As an experiment you can take the torus divided in 7 cobording regions at https://www3.amherst.edu/~nstarr/torus/index.html, project it in a rectangular sheet of paper (without the colors) and see what's the resulting map.

Comment: I mean: it is still a torus. The other countries don't go away, just because of the change in perspective. Why would it go back to being 4? You still have to accompdate for overlap along the Z-axis, even if the map is flat, the globe/region that it depicts is not [flat]

Comment: Let me be clearer, maybe. Each region on the original torus maps onto a specific closed subset of the rectangular map. Some of these images may overlap. In general, you will have $2^n - 1$ _disjoint_ "intersections" (one for each combination of the original n countries being or not intersected), of which some can be empty. In the end, those $2^n - 1$ intersections are just closed subsets of the rectangular map, and they can be colored with 4 colors. Overlaps are being taken into account even if all the regions have very complex intersections.

Comment: To be more precise, you need only to consider intersection that have nonempty interior, otherwise they won't be colored at all.

Comment: Interesting... but I don't follow... are you saying that you would cut the torus up, and display it as a flattened rectangle, like an orange peel, but from a donut? And then as a cut-up "donut peel" it would once again only need 4 colors?

Comment: Check a simple example using geogebra https://imgur.com/a/vkh9D the three regions the projected donut is divided into (left orange, center mixed, right green) are just different bounded regions in the map.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand where the number $7$ is coming from. If you allow the bridges, then we are not colouring planar graphs anymore: we are colouring arbitrary graphs and, for that, no finite number of colours would suffice.

Imagine you have $n$ countries, and imagine there is a bridge between **each** two of them. (The bridges may be very long and very high, some bridges may need to go over other bridges.)

Think: how many colours do you need in that case? $n$, I guess, as a minimum, just to colour the territories, plus whatever else you want to add in order to colour the rest.

Comment: I was reading the answers but now they all say "[math processing error]" is it doing that onyour end too?

Comment: @user179283 It is all fine on my end...

Comment: This semi-unrelated, but could you or someone you have good faith in, take a look at this " https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2580652/515443 "  question of mine? it's been flying under the radar for awhile now, and it's eat'n me up inside... ...cos the answer relates to a creative project I'm working on, and I want tto maintasin as much accuracy as possible

Comment: Oh, then maybe it's just bad cell service on my end; if so, it should come back eventually (hopefully)

Comment: @user179283 I will have a look but cannot guarantee anything. Have you thought of offering a bounty on your question?

Comment: I refreshed the page, and the answers are back. I am relieved...

Comment: This is the first time that I have heard of these "bounties", please do explain. I'm a new user, and also on the mobile site (site not app) so the gui and ux are a little ackward, but I'm braving them

Comment: @user179283 Please see https://math.stackexchange.com/help/bounty. However, you may not have enough reputation to start a bounty... ignore for now.

Comment: 7 came from my memory, I remembered hearing that a donut shaped globe with one whole requires 7 colors. If my memory failed me, and 7 is wrong: then the whole thing is off-kilter. But I gave this " http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TorusColoring.html " a cursory read, and it seemed to corraberate that. On an important tangent: I was imagining a one bridge system, but I see now that there is no stopping the bridges from escalating to a point of absurdly extreme numbers [of bridges], so my bad, for not clarifying and/or realizing

Comment: Can do. Checking it out now

Comment: @user179283 No, 7 is right for a torus, but if you don't restrict what can be joined, we are not talking about a torus anymore. In the worst case, each territory will be joined with each other territory, and you will need a different colour for each territory.

Comment: @user8734617 As for the other question, if I've understood it correctly, the answer is easy but surprising; please have a look.